# Недоступный компонент

Tags: java, swing

Пишу простой компонент пользовательского интерфейса. Завожу объект типа JComponent и переопределяю метод paintComponent. Компонент умеет отображать картинку, заданную в качестве параметра и xитрым способом дорисовывать что-то поверx картинки и рядом с ней. Здесь, для примера, пусть она перечеркивает картинку красным. Компонент реагирует на события мыши и т.д. Иногда требуется показать, что наша "кнопка" недоступна пользователю, disabled, серенькая. Как сделать так, чтобы наша "кнопка" становилась серенькой? Про узоры, которые я дорисовываю более менее понятно: я могу поставить условие, какой цвет выбирать. А что делать с картинкой? Как её отобразить?

Код примерно такой:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        JComponent c = new JComponent() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                ImageIcon ia = new ImageIcon("icon.png");
                ia.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0);
                g.setColor(isEnabled()? Color.RED : Color.GRAY);
                g.drawLine(0, 0, ia.getIconWidth(), ia.getIconHeight());
            }
        };
        c.setEnabled(false);
        frame.add(c);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для ImageIcon - [LookAndFeel.getDisabledIcon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/LookAndFeel.html), первый параметр - типа JComponent, согласно документации может быть равен null:

```
ImageIcon ia = new ImageIcon("icon.png");
if (!isEnabled())
    ia = UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getDisabledIcon(null, ia); 
ia.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Поступите, как с цветом: создайте второе, обесцвеченное, изображение, и переключайтесь между ними с помощью `isEnabled()`. Только сохраните ссылки на картинки в членах класса, не нужно создавать каждый раз новую иконку при вызове `paintComponent()` - это происходит достаточно часто.

Comment: А как мне эту обесцвеченную картинку создать?

Comment: Так вы хотите программно сделать картинку обесцвеченной?

Comment: Само собой. Не делать же мне вторую картинку в фотошопе, чтобы получилось в два раза больше ресурсов у приложения. Это какой-то неполноценный компонент получится.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не хотите заготавливать заранее обесцвеченную картинку, то вы можете обесцветить её с помощью фильтров или просто заранее создать BufferedImage у которого просто нет цветов. В интернете полно примеров. Можно легко найти по запросу Java2D convert image to grayscale. Вот пара простых примеров:

- [пример с красной тачкой](http://blog.codebeach.com/2008/03/convert-color-image-to-gray-scale-image.html)
- [пример с BufferedImage](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/112296/1526714#post1526714)